# Do the 3.5 books ask you to refer to 3.0 books?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, conversion, books

I noticed some of the 3.5 manuals refer to books like Manual of the Planes and Oriental Adventures, but when one of my friends found those books, they were 3.0 edition. Is that right, or were there 3.5 reprints of books like these?

Answer (score 11):

**There's a rule for this!**

Some 3.0 content is still 'current' for 3.5. The official rule from Wizards of the Coast is that any content that didn't get updated (that is, printed into a new 3.5 book) is still valid and is thus usable with 3.5. Oriental Adventures and Manual of the Planes are indeed two such books, requiring only minor adjustments to the skill system(s) present to be in accordance with 3.5's slightly smaller skill list.

Comment: "Are you sure you want to discard your draft?" "Yes, Gareth just ninja'd my answer." Might be worth mentioning that *Oriental Adventures* got a quick update in an issue of *Dragon*. And the *Planar Handbook* is kind-of sort-of the 3.5-version of *Manual of the Planes*, though you can just use both since they don't overlap that much.

Comment: Heh, sorry man.

Comment: Awesome. Now if only I could tell what the deal is with this "Sword and Sorcery" stuff they got tons of when we sent them to get DnD 3.5 books.

Comment: You should link to this official rule, since I've never been able to find it.  (Probably search failure on my part, but it's really necessary for a complete answer.)

Comment: you could also add that some 3.0 manuals have an "errata" in order for them to comply to 3.5 rules: http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a

Comment: Cobalt: Sword and Sorcery is an imprint used by White Wolf publishing to publish D&D 3.5e Books under the OGL as well as other D20 materials not specifically D&D related.