# How do I quickly find the official errata for any book?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, errata

When answering questions, I often find that I want to double-check that my answer is in-line with the most current version of the rules. Though I can often recognise that I need to check the errata when drawing on a book that I'm very familiar with, when an answer calls for drawing from many sources I usually won't have all that knowledge at my fingertips. What is the easiest way to know that a book has errata and where to find it?

Comment: Have you not checked out the WOTC Archives? All of their errata is there including web only content (Such as the Wild Cohort Feat).

Comment: @Ruut Link? I can't find it with a quick Google.

Comment: Complete Champion errata! *pout*

Comment: @NiteCyper as stated above - http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/we

Comment: VTR as this is not actually a duplicate, and the answer to this question is buried so hard in the "duplicate" that nobody will find it. [See Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/non-duplicate-question-with-answer-in-another-question)

Comment: The status of whether this question should be open or closed [is being discussed here on meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/non-duplicate-question-with-answer-in-another-question).

Comment: Since you're attributing it to me - this isn't the title nor type of question I had in mind. What I described was asking about a process of identifying what has errata and how to find that errata. Stopping at the first step is _probably_ kinda pointless and weird, since finding out errata exists is often going to involve _discovering_ the errata. Maybe that's not the kind of question you want to ask, but nevertheless that's what I was suggesting.

Comment: @NiteCyper take it easy. We're not here just to close-vote it, we're here to make sure it's in a form it can actually receive good answers. Putting it on hold is part of that process sometimes - and so is re-opening it afterwards. Also, so is talking with you and working out how it can be _made to work._ Take it slow, this might take some back and forth from various users before it's worked out. I presume the answers aren't needed urgently, since for something like this they're unlikely to arrive rapidly anyway.

Comment: Doing it in steps is not necessary. Let's focus on the problem, and make the question about that. *Engage editor mode...*

Comment: There; how does that look? Does it capture your problem well? Does it miss anything important, or misrepresent anything?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, the title question was never my question, but others insist that that it should be the question, so whatever. Secondly, I wanted to ask about updates as well because I draw material from books that were potentially unupdated 3e; my question was about verifying material's potential incompatibility as a result of unaccounted errata and/or update, hence a list.

Comment: @NiteCyper related: [How do you tell if a D&D book is 3.0 or 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/how-do-you-tell-if-a-dd-book-is-3-0-or-3-5), [Do the 3.5 books ask you to refer to 3.0 books?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25385/do-the-3-5-books-ask-you-to-refer-to-3-0-books) and [Does the Rules Compendium overrule the core books?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/does-the-rules-compendium-overrule-the-core-books) (just because the answers introduce you to primary sources, which is how you determine which manual to use)

Answer (score 11):

### Use the Wayback Machine

The Wizards of the Coast website used to have an archive page of downloads for all the 3/3.5e errata, which would have been found at [this link](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata) while it still existed. Unfortunately, at some point in WotC's cycle of website redesigns it went away and they no longer seem to be hosting the files anywhere.

Luckily this is not a problem for us because the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) has snapshots of the old site which we can use instead. The most recent working snapshot it has of that page is [here, from November 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata).

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1406/%7E/d%26d%3A-3.5-and-3.0-errata-and-faq) is where all of the **3.0/3.5 errata** and **faqs** were moved. All you have to do is navigate to the [main DnD archive page](https://magic.wizards.com/en/go) and search for "*3.5 errata*" in the upper-right hand search bar.

To clarify: If the book is listed, then it has errata. Most of the file names also include dates.

Comment: I'm not seeing Complete Champion errata...

Comment: @NiteCyper A fair number of 3.5 materials got very limited or no errata.  (They were weirdly reluctant to issue errata for that edition; lots of very obvious mistakes were never officially corrected in that way.)

Comment: @starwed My point is that [Complete Champion errata](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/Errata_CompleteChampion.zip) does exist, but Dyndrilliac('s answer) does not include it nor warns of their answer's dearth of it

Comment: @NiteCyper I simply linked you to the page where Wizards archived their 3.0/3.5 errata. If they failed to link to existing errata on their archive page, that's an issue you will need to take up with Wizards. There is nothing I can do about it; I don't maintain their archives, after all.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start looking for errata is the [archived errata page on Wizards.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata). They're sorted by version (3.5/3.0), then by book. I don't know of any case where there's an official errata that isn't listed there. The Complete Champion errata is listed there, for example.

[In addition, some 3.0 books have a conversion guide to update them to 3.5.](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111163406/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a) These don't say they're errata, but they're also the only non-homebrew conversions from 3.0 to 3.5, so for something like the Monster Manual II they're essentially the 3.5 version.

**Official Things That Are Not Errata**

Then there's things that aren't errata but still put out by Wizards, like the FAQ ([available over here](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1406/%7E/d%26d%3A-3.5-and-3.0-errata-and-faq)). I only mention it to be able to mention that it's *not errata*. The same goes with the "rules of the game" articles that were published on their website.

These things can be useful and I've used them before when something particularly weird needed sorting out, bu they're not errata and don't override the core rules/errata. They do sometimes explain things better, and if they do change a rule, any DM is free to use the other version in their game if they want to.